# Knockout Set name of element

Tags: html, knockout.js

How can i get the input field below to be rendered as follows

```
<input name= "NIALL" type="text" />
```

using the knockout model and html below. NOTE that I want to create the name of the element based on the knockout model. Heres what ive tried but it dosent work.

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" data-bind="value: stringValue,attr: { 'name': ElementName}" />
```

**//Knockout model**

```
function MyViewModel() {

  var self = this;
  self.stringValue = "sss";
  self.ElementName = "NIALL";
}
```

Comment: It does work. Check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hqkH/1/). You've messed up something else (did you rememver to initialize view model and apply bindings?).

Comment: It will show up in Chrome. IE wont keep its html up to date with changes, it just uses the original. Debugging with IE is generally a poor experience (like everything else in IE).

Comment: I am having the same problem in IE8 Standards Mode. Name simply does not update on a radio input.

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine, it will work in IE's developer tools if you hit Refresh on the dev tools toolbar. Or look at it with firebuglite's bookmarklet from inside IE.